# What ist the difference between ontouchend and ontouchleave?

Tags: c#, blazor

It seems like for the following question Google should give an answer but (for me) it doesn't.
What ist the difference between the events `ontouchend` and `ontouchleave` or `ontouchstart` and `ontouchenter`, respectively?

Many thanks

Philipp

Comment: are these events related to blazor?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#:~:text=Touch,ontouchleave%2C%20ontouchcancel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to consider your widget as a collision box that react to touch on screen

ontouchend() is called when you lift off you finger off the screen, won't activate if you first slide ouside the colision box.

ontouchleave() is called if your finger touche the colision box werever it come from et leave eitheir by lift up or sliding your finger out of the colision box.

ontouchenter() is as soon your finger enter the colision box

ontouchstart() is only called is your finger directly touched the collision box, its make to avoid accidental activation by sliding from another place of the screen

Comment: My app does not work with the `ontouchleave` event, so I created a [blazor fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vebqn7zk). With dev tools emulating a mobile device or even on my smartphone, I am neither able to trigger `ontouchleave` nor `ontouchenter`. How can these events be triggered? P. S. `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend` behave like `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`.